# Excel COMException : 0x800A03EC Document not saved

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010, excel-interop, comexception

I am using Interop.Excel in my WinForms application. The application is used to copy some sheets from one workbook to newly created one.

The newly created workbook is saved when I don't copy shapes. But, when I copy shapes into newly created sheet, the workbook is not saved and COMException is raised with message "**Document not saved**".

Scenario :

I am working with three workbooks simultaneously.

*MainWorkbook* - this workbook contains data to be written into new workbook.

*ResourceWorkbook* - this contains sheets that are copied into new workbook.

*OutputWorkbook* - this is the result workbook.

Step 1: Open *MainWorkbook*. Get data to write in *OutputWorkbook*.

Step 2: Write data into *OutputWorkbook*.

Step 3: Open *ResourceWorkbook* from resource file for copying the sheets.

Step 4: Copy sheets from *ResourceWorkbook* into *OutputWorkbook*.

Step 5: Save *OutputWorkbook*.

In step 5, if there are no sheets with images copied in step 4, then the OutputWorkbook is saved. But, if there are sheets containing images, the OutputWorkbook is not saved.

I am using VS2010 and MS Office 2010.

Comment: First try overwriting existing excel with shapes, if it still does not works check in your system by creating a new excel file & copy the same shapes & try saving. If it gets saved, then it is code enhancement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save your OutputWorkbook.
Reopen it and then try to copy. See if it works.

Comment: that worked like a charm. Was the problem because of not saving the workbook before copying??